# Other administrator cannot change printer properties or security permissions

Tags: windows-7, permissions, printer

Printers added by other administrators users on the same machine cannot have its properties or permissions changed by any administrators but the one who created it.

The Administrators group DOES have the Manage Printers permission.

Is that behavior normal? How can I workaround it?

EDIT: Here is a step by step to reproduce the "problem".

1) Add a new printer.

2) Create another administrator user (let's call it TempAdmin).

3) Log in as TempAdmin

4) Open printer properties and try to change the port the printer is installed (in my case this is disabled).

Comment: Is this part of an Active Directory Domain?

Comment: No, all of them are local users, and the printer in question is a network printer. I can't, for example, change the port the printer is installed, only the owner/creator can.

Comment: Is there a local printer policy in place?

Comment: No, this happened in a fresh installed machine.